# My Mi Mini Wifi Router isn't working

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot, additional-drivers, wifi-hardware-switch

I recently came to Ubuntu from Windows 10. I used a Mi Mini Pocket Wifi router USB device(/MI WLAN USB Adapter) for creating hotspot from my computer. But, in Ubuntu, I can't use that. I installed a pakage from mi website.
but still it isn't working. I tried to install the driver of Windows on wine but it still doesn't work.
So what should I do now?
My system hardware detects the usb but it isn't working.

[image]

Comment: If it's a WiFi-router, the router is not relevant. The only question is your computer? Is wireless working for other purposes? What PC is it?

Comment: @vidarlo , its a usb device that creates wireless hotspot.

Comment: So it's not a wifi router, it's some sort of network card?

Comment: yes............